# powershell loop returning some incorrect values but not all

Tags: .net, powershell

I have a script that runs against a directory and looks for files in it. Based on a portion of the filename containing the internal extension, it will then email the file to the associated user. I have it 90% working, it will email the correct person the correct file, but the variables in the email subject line are wrong. For example, a file intended for Bob goes to Bob, but the email subject line indicates Joe as well as the CallerID of Joe's call.

```
$Path = 'c:\test2'
$delim = '-'
$delim2 = '@'
$Port = "587"
$SMTPUsername = "voicemails@test.com"
$EncryptedPasswordFile = "c:\test\voicemails.com.securestring"
$SecureStringPassword = Get-Content -Path $EncryptedPasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString
$EmailCredential = New-Object -TypeName Management.Automation.PSCredential($SMTPUsername,$SecureStringPassword )
$DestFolder = 'C:\test2\Processed'
#phone extensions & associated email address
$extensions = @{
  '1000'= 'joe@test.com';
  '23' = 'bob@test.com';
  '765'= 'alice@test.com'
    }
$File = Get-ChildItem $Path -Name
$File | Foreach-object {
    $FirstName = $null
    $nameArray = $_.Split($delim)
    $newName = $nameArray[2]+" "+($nameArray[0].substring(0,8))
    $ext = $nameArray[3]
    $callerID = $nameArray[2]
    $Datestamp = ($nameArray[0].substring(0,8))
    $emailAddress = $extensions[$ext]
    $FirstNameArray = $emailAddress.Split($delim2)
    $FirstName = $FirstNameArray[0]
     $SMTPMessage = @{
        To = $emailAddress
        From = 'voicemails@test.com'
        Subject = $Subject
        Smtpserver = '192.168.1.9'
        }
    $SMTPBody = 'Voicemail redirected message'
    $Subject = "Call Recording on $Datestamp from ($CallerID) to $FirstName"
    Send-MailMessage -Credential $EmailCredential @SMTPMessage -Body $SMTPBody -Attachments $_ -Port $Port
}
```

Some sample filenames I'm running it against:

- 20180705072823-1530804495.22-15555552367-1000-Inbound.wav
- 20180705072823-1530804495.22-15555551234-23-Inbound.wav
- 20180705072823-1530804495.22-15555557791-765-Inbound.wav

I've tried to set the values to $null for each loop but doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen because the hashtable is initialized before `$subject` is set.

```
$SMTPMessage = @{
    To = $emailAddress
    From = 'voicemails@test.com'
    Subject = $Subject # Uses old $subject
    Smtpserver = '192.168.1.9'
    }
# Set new subject
$Subject = "Call Recording on $Datestamp from ($CallerID) to $FirstName"
```

A simple example for illustration purposes:

```
$subject = "Subject 1"
$SMTPMessage = @{
    To = 'Rec 1'
    Subject = $subject
}
$SMTPMessage

$SMTPMessage = @{
    To = 'Rec 2'
    Subject = $subject
}
$subject = "Subject 2"
$SMTPMessage

Name                           Value
----                           -----
To                             Rec 1
Subject                        Subject 1
To                             Rec 2
Subject                        Subject 1 # Uses the value before reassignment
```

Comment: thank you, that's what it was. I removed the hashtable and just hardcoded the variables into the Send-MailMessage command and it is working as expected now.